# Analog of php serialize in c#

Tags: c#, php

There in C# available any methods like serialize and unserialize in php?

I need it for best way to transfer an array through network.

Comment: Look at the [System.Runtime.Serialization Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.aspx)

Comment: XmlSerializer, BinaryFormatter, JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using basic `System.Xml.Serialization` to serialise and deserialise an instance of a class. Of course you can do a lot more with this like using [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx) to control how the serialiser does its work, etc.

And if you want to use JSON format, then you can use [JavascriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) which is very similar or better yet use [JSON.Net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) which is much better.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

static void Main()
{
    //create something silly to serialise:
    var thing = new MyThing(){Name="My thing", ID=0};
    thing.SubThings.Add(new MySubThing{ID=1});
    thing.SubThings.Add(new MySubThing{ID=2});


    //serialise to XML using an XDocument as the output 
    //(you can use any stream writer though)
    //first create the serialiser
    var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyThing));

    //then create an XDocument and get an XmlWriter from it
    var output= new XDocument();
    using(var writer = output.CreateWriter())
    {
       serialiser.Serialize(writer,thing);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());

    /*expected output:
     <MyThing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Name>My thing</Name>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <SubThings>
        <MySubThing>
          <ID>1</ID>
        </MySubThing>
        <MySubThing>
          <ID>2</ID>
        </MySubThing>
      </SubThings>
    </MyThing>

    */

    //Send across network
    //...
    //On other end of the connection, deserialise from XML.
    //Again using XDocument as the input
    //or any Stream Reader containing the data
    var source = output.ToString();
    var input = XDocument.Parse(source);
    MyThing newThing = null;
    using (var reader = input.CreateReader())
    {
      newThing = serialiser.Deserialize(reader) as MyThing;
    }
    if (newThing!=null)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("newThing.ID={0}, It has {1} Subthings",newThing.ID,newThing.SubThings.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        //something went wrong with the de-serialisation.
    }
}

//just some silly classes for the sample code.
public class MyThing
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public List<MySubThing> SubThings{get;set;}
   public MyThing()
   {
        SubThings=new List<MySubThing>();
   }
}

public class MySubThing
{
  public int ID{get;set;}
}
```

Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

MS reccomends that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/et91as27.aspx

Also you can use something like this (here is for doubles, but can be modified to any datatype):

Serialize:

```
 public string Serialize(double[] Source, string Separator)
    {
        string result = "";
        foreach (double d in Source) result += d.ToString()+Separator;
        return result;
    }
```

Unserialize

```
public double[] UnSerialize(string Source, char[] separators)
{
    //splitting Source array by separators   "1|2|3" => Split by '|' => [1],[2],[3]
    string[] tmp = Source.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    double[] result = new double[tmp.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<tmp.Length) {result[i]=Convert.ToDouble(tmp[i]);}
    return result;
}
```