# How do I Convert XmlNode to C# Objects?

Tags: c#, xml

I consume a third-party web service that uses SOAP XML. I construct my XML request and get XML back like this:

```
<GetCustomers xmlns="">
  <Header>
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <Type>GetCustomers</Type>
    <GeneratedDate>07/11/2013 13:30</GeneratedDate>
  </Header>
  <ResultMessage>
    <Message>7 Customers found</Message>
    <Code>CustomerFound</Code>
    <Success>true</Success>
  </ResultMessage>
  <Customer>
    <CustomerName>CUSTOMER ABC</CustomerName>
    <CustomerID>33</CustomerID>
    <CustomerCode></CustomerCode>
  </Customer>
```

It returns it as an object type XmlNode and I want to convert this response into a ViewModel I have created as part of an MVC 4 app I am building. What is an approach that will work?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the full XML into a string first:

```
string xml = response.OuterXml.ToString();
```

Then use XDocument:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

Now use LINQ to XML to select each Customer element and create a list:

```
var obj = (from element in xDoc.Descendants("GetCustomers").Elements("Customer")
           select new {
              ID = element.Element("CustomerID").Value,
              Name element.Element("CustomerName").Value,
              Code = element.Element("CustomerCode").Value
           }).ToList();
```

I am sure there are many better ways to now convert this into my ViewModel data but this is how I did it:

```
foreach (var item in obj)
{
    RMCustomer customer = new RMCustomer();
    if (item.ID != null && item.ID.Length > 0)
    {
        customer.RMInternalUniqueID = Convert.ToInt32(item.ID);
    }

    if (item.Code != null && item.Code.Length > 0)
    {
        customer.CustomerRMExternalID = Convert.ToInt32(item.Code);
    }
    else
    {
        customer.CustomerRMExternalID = null;
    }
    if (item.Name != null && item.Name.Length > 0)
    {
        customer.CustomerName = item.Name;
    }
    if (customer != null)
    {
        roadMarqueCustomers.Add(customer);
    }
}
```

I should point out my ViewModel is simply:

```
public class RMCustomer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerRMInternalUniqueID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CustomerRMExternalID { get; set; }
}
```

Finally:

```
 return roadMarqueCustomers;
```

Comment: If you knew the answer, why did you ask the question?

Comment: Because I was searching for ages to find an answer and couldn't get various other methods to work so I thought I'd share what I found in case it helps other newbies like me. I thought it was within the rules as per this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Answering your own question is totally fine within SO.

Comment: @dav_i, IMO, yes if you find the answer after asking the question but not when you already know the answer.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko [SO Blog - It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) - "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."

Comment: @MikeRouse Just a quick hint to help you - instead of doing `someString != null && someString.Length > 0` you can do `String.IsNullOrEmpty(someString)` or if any of `null`, `" "`, `"   "`, `"       "`, etc is not wanted - `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someString)`

Comment: Also, you could use XMLSerializer class to perform the actual mapping from XML, I have an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19448271/1362136

Comment: Or you can let someone else do all the lifting, including the consuming of the web-service with something like [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/).  You create the DTO's (Data Transfer Objects) for the service and it consumes the web-service and hands you your DTO's.